# Flutter: Font Awesome Pro update fail

Tags: flutter, dart, font-awesome

I was trying to implement the font awesome pro icon but when the documentation ask me to update using `./tool/update.sh` it come out this error. Any solution how to solve this ?

```
Custom icons.json found, using local data only.
./tool/update.sh: line 6: dart: command not found
./tool/update.sh: line 7: dart: command not found
./tool/update.sh: line 8: dartfmt: command not found
./tool/update.sh: line 9: dartfmt: command not found
```

Comment: any update on this? I'm facing the same exact issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the exact same problem. The program is available <flutter_home>/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dartfmt path.

You can either update the PATH env variable from your shell.. or change the script to use this path (hard coded).

Here is the example:

```
<FLUTTER_HOME>/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dartfmt -w ./lib/font_awesome_flutter.dart
<FLUTTER_HOME>/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dartfmt -w ./example/lib/icons.dart
```